# ffmpeg how to allow a file extension

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

New ffmpeg version check for file extension due to security issue 
[in ffmpeg.org](https://patchwork.ffmpeg.org/patch/3821/) that use `#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128`

since the key usually doesn't use file extension or use *.key extension
so example

```
ffmpeg -i "C:\streamingtest.m3u8" -c copy "test.ts"
```

inside the m3u8 I have :

```
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="C:/keytest.key"
```

And ffmpeg will spew an error

> [hls,applehttp @ 0000000000dc6460] Filename extension of
>   'C:/keytest.key' is not a common multimedia extension, blocked for
>   security reasons. If you wish to override this adjust
>   allowed_extensions, you can set it to 'ALL' to allow all Unable to
>   open key file c:/keytest.key

But it doesn't explain how to use the ALL options in allowed_extensions

So how do i allow key extension in ffmpeg or allow all extension

Thanks

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It's a private option of the HLS demuxer, so

```
ffmpeg -allowed_extensions ALL -i "C:\streamingtest.m3u8" -c copy "test.ts"
```

Comment: i tried -allowed_extensions=all but i guess i was wrong :D, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is directive for the player **-allowed_extensions**

try the following:

```
ffplay -allowed_extensions ALL index.m3u8
```

it is working form me with the key stored in the local folder